# How to perform element-wise subtraction between two vectors?

Tags: rust

I have to `Vec`s: `vec_a` and `vec_b`. Both the same size. I want to perform element-wise subtraction between the two vectors and save the answer in a third vector `vec_c`. For example:

```
vec_a = [1, 2, 3]
vec_b = [0, 2, -3]
vec_c = vec_a - vec_b = [1, 0, 6]
```

The solution I've come with is this function:

```
pub fn elementwise_subtraction(vec_a: Vec<i32>, vec_b: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec_c = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..vec_a.len() {
        vec_c.push(vec_a[i] - vec_b[i]);
    }
    vec_c
}
```

I feel like this is a bit verbose for a pretty simple operation. Is there a better/more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing built in, you have to implement it yourself or use a third-party crate.

Anyway, you can continue to improve your code using functional programming:

```rust
pub fn elementwise_subtraction(vec_a: Vec<i32>, vec_b: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec_a.into_iter().zip(vec_b).map(|(a, b)| a - b).collect()
}

let vec_a = vec![1, 2, 3];
let vec_b = vec![0, 2, -3];
let vec_c = elementwise_subtraction(vec_a, vec_b);
assert_eq!(vec_c, [1, 0, 6])
```

If you want to make it more generic (e.g. accepting both slices or `Vec`, any subtractable type):

```rust
use std::ops::Sub;

pub fn elementwise_subtraction<N, IA, IB, F>(a: IA, b: IB) -> F
where
    N: Sub,
    IA: IntoIterator<Item = N>,
    IB: IntoIterator<Item = N>,
    F: FromIterator<N> + FromIterator<<N as Sub>::Output>,
{
    a.into_iter().zip(b).map(|(a, b)| a - b).collect()
}

let vec_a = [1, 2, 3];
let vec_b = [0, 2, -3];
let vec_c: Vec<_> = elementwise_subtraction(vec_a, vec_b);
assert_eq!(vec_c, [1, 0, 6])
```

[Try it on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f7ebe49014d8a9b085cd3a7d6978317)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `zip` and `map`:

```
fn main() {
    let vec_a = [1, 2, 3];
    let vec_b = [0, 2, -3];

    let vec_c: Vec<i32> = vec_a
        .iter()
        .zip(vec_b)
        .map(|(elem_a, elem_b)| elem_a - elem_b)
        .collect();

    for elem_c in vec_c {
        println!("{}", elem_c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method is likely the most efficient way since it uses straight indexing, but an iterator method could look like this:

```rust
assert_eq!(
    vec_a
        .iter()
        .zip(vec_b)
        .map(|(a, b)| a - b)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
    vec![1, 0, 6]
);
```

"Better" is always subjective, so if performance is your priority you should benchmark different methods; I've been surprised by results before.

Comment: I'd expect `zip()` to be _faster_ because it lacks bounds checking (also meaning it could vectorize), and contrary to the OP's code it also allocates the vector with the right capacity ahead of time (although this is fixable for the OP's code). But I cannot be sure without benchmarking of course.